# JSF Custom component Tag class is skipped?

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, el

I've managed to get my component work with plain Strings and now I'm trying to add the possibility of parsing a `ValueExpression`.

To do that, I'm editing my EmoticonOutputTextTag file, to add in the `setProperties()` the evaluation of the expression.

But I've noticed that this method is NEVER called.

Seems like that this class is unused and I don't know why.

In fact, in my `setProperties()` I've put this line : `eot.setInputText("randomText");` and I was hoping that my component would show that..Indeed, my component shows the value passed in the JSF page, so I'm guessing that this method is not called.

What should I do?

Here's the code :

EmoticonOutputText.java

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.unilife.emoticonOutputText;

import javax.el.ValueExpression;
import javax.faces.component.UIOutput;

/**
 *
 * @author stefano
 */
public class EmoticonOutputText extends UIOutput {

    private static final String COMP_FAMILY = "javax.faces.Output";

    /**
     * Get the value of COMPONENT_FAMILY
     *
     * @return the value of COMPONENT_FAMILY
     */
    @Override
    public String getFamily() {
        return COMP_FAMILY;
    }
    private static final String RENDERER_TYPE = "EmoticonOutputTextRenderer";

    /**
     * Get the value of RENDERER_TYPE
     *
     * @return the value of RENDERER_TYPE
     */
    @Override
    public String getRendererType() {
        return RENDERER_TYPE;
    }
    private String style;

    /**
     * Get the value of style
     *
     * @return the value of style
     */
    public String getStyle() {
        return style;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of style
     *
     * @param style new value of style
     */
    public void setStyle(String style) {
        this.style = style;
    }
    private String styleClass;

    /**
     * Get the value of styleClass
     *
     * @return the value of styleClass
     */
    public String getStyleClass() {
        return styleClass;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of styleClass
     *
     * @param styleClass new value of styleClass
     */
    public void setStyleClass(String styleClass) {
        this.styleClass = styleClass;
    }
    private String inputText;

    /**
     * Get the value of inputText
     *
     * @return the value of inputText
     */
    public String getInputText() {
        return inputText;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of inputText
     *
     * @param inputText new value of inputText
     */
    public void setInputText(String inputText) {
        this.inputText = inputText;
    }
}
```

EmoticonOutputTextTag.java

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.unilife.emoticonOutputText;

import javax.el.ValueExpression;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentELTag;

/**
 *
 * @author stefano
 */
public class EmoticonOutputTextTag extends UIComponentELTag {

    private static final String COMP_TYPE = "EmoticonOutputTextTag";
    private static final String RENDERER_TYPE = "EmoticonOutputTextRenderer";
    private String style;
    private String styleClass;
    private ValueExpression inputText;

    public void setStyle(String style) {
        this.style = style;
    }

    public void setStyleClass(String styleClass) {
        this.styleClass = styleClass;
    }

    public void setInputText(ValueExpression inputText) {
        this.inputText = inputText;
    }

    @Override
    public String getComponentType() {
        return COMP_TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    public String getRendererType() {
        return RENDERER_TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    protected void setProperties(UIComponent component) {
        super.setProperties(component);
        EmoticonOutputText eot = (EmoticonOutputText)component;        
        if(style != null){
            eot.setStyle(style);
        }
        if(styleClass != null){
            eot.setStyleClass(styleClass);
        }
        if(inputText != null){
//            eot.setInputText(inputText.getExpressionString());
            eot.setInputText("randomText");
        }        
    }    
}
```

EmoticonOutputTextRenderer.java

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.unilife.emoticonOutputText;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.context.ResponseWriter;
import javax.faces.render.Renderer;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

/**
 *
 * @author stefano
 */
public class EmoticonOutputTextRenderer extends Renderer {

    //Contiene la corrispondenza tra la stringa da sostituire e il nome dell'emoticon
    private static final HashMap<String, String> emoticons = new HashMap<>();
    //Contiene il percorso dei files delle emoticon
    private final String basePath = ((ServletContext) (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext())).getContextPath() + "/resources/images/emoticons/";

    public EmoticonOutputTextRenderer() {
        parseEmoticons();
    }

    private void parseEmoticons(){
        //Not needed 
    }

    @Override
    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) throws IOException {
        EmoticonOutputText eot = (EmoticonOutputText) component;
        ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
        //Aggiungiamo l'eventuale stile CSS o direttamente la classe
        writer.startElement("span", null);
        if(eot.getStyle()!=null && !eot.getStyle().isEmpty()){
            writer.writeAttribute("style", eot.getStyle(), null);
        }
        if(eot.getStyleClass()!=null && !eot.getStyleClass().isEmpty()){
            writer.writeAttribute("class", eot.getStyleClass(), null);
        }
        //Andiamo ad effettuare il parse vero e proprio, sostituendo le emoticons come le immagini
        for(String str : eot.getInputText().split(" ")){
            if(emoticons.containsKey(str)){ //Se riconosco l'emoticon allora scrivo l'immagine
                writer.startElement("img", null);
                writer.writeAttribute("src", emoticons.get(str) + ".gif", null);
                writer.endElement("img");
                writer.writeText(" ", null);
            } else { //Altrimenti aggiungo semplicemente la parola
                writer.writeText(str + " ", null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

unilife.taglib.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE facelet-taglib PUBLIC
"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Facelet Taglib 1.0//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/facelet-taglib_1_0.dtd">
<facelet-taglib>
    <namespace>http://unilife.it/tags</namespace>
    <tag>
        <tag-name>EmoticonOutputText</tag-name>
        <description>
            OutputText con la possibilità di mostrare Emoticons
        </description>
        <component>
            <component-type>EmoticonOutputText</component-type>
            <renderer-type>EmoticonOutputTextRenderer</renderer-type>
        </component>
        <attribute>
            <name>style</name>            
            <type>java.lang.String</type>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>styleClass</name>            
            <type>java.lang.String</type>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>inputText</name>
            <required>true</required>            
            <type>java.lang.String</type>
        </attribute>
    </tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="1.2" 
                xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd">
    <component>
        <component-type>
            EmoticonOutputText
        </component-type>
        <component-class>
            com.unilife.emoticonOutputText.EmoticonOutputText
        </component-class>
    </component>

    <render-kit>
        <renderer>
            <description>
                OutputText che permette il rendering di emoticons al posto delle combinazioni di tasti
            </description>
            <component-family>
                javax.faces.Output
            </component-family>
            <renderer-type>
                EmoticonOutputTextRenderer
            </renderer-type>
            <renderer-class>
                com.unilife.emoticonOutputText.EmoticonOutputTextRenderer
            </renderer-class>
        </renderer>
    </render-kit>  
</faces-config>
```

EDIT :
I've edited something after lu4242's answer but now I've got a ClassCastException!

EmoticonOutputTextTag.java

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.unilife.emoticonOutputText;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.el.ValueExpression;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.view.facelets.ComponentConfig;
import javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletContext;
import javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttribute;
import javax.faces.view.facelets.TagHandler;

/**
 *
 * @author stefano
 */

public class EmoticonOutputTextTag extends TagHandler {

    private static final String COMP_TYPE = "EmoticonOutputTextTag";
    private static final String RENDERER_TYPE = "EmoticonOutputTextRenderer";
    private String style;
    private String styleClass;
    private ValueExpression inputText;

    public EmoticonOutputTextTag(ComponentConfig config) {
        super(config);
    }

    public void setStyle(String style) {
        this.style = style;
    }

    public void setStyleClass(String styleClass) {
        this.styleClass = styleClass;
    }

    public void setInputText(ValueExpression inputText) {
        this.inputText = inputText;
    }

    @Override
    public void apply(FaceletContext fc, UIComponent uic) throws IOException {
        EmoticonOutputText eot = (EmoticonOutputText) uic;        
        TagAttribute ta = this.getRequiredAttribute("inputText");
        ValueExpression ve = ta.getValueExpression(fc, String.class);
        if(ve.isLiteralText()){
            eot.setInputText(ve.getExpressionString());
        } else {
            eot.setInputText((String)ve.getValue(fc));
        }
    }
}
```

unilife.taglib.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE facelet-taglib PUBLIC
"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Facelet Taglib 1.0//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/facelet-taglib_1_0.dtd">
<facelet-taglib>
    <namespace>http://unilife.it/tags</namespace>
    <tag>
        <tag-name>EmoticonOutputText</tag-name>
        <description>
            OutputText con la possibilità di mostrare Emoticons
        </description>
        <component>
            <component-type>EmoticonOutputText</component-type>
            <renderer-type>EmoticonOutputTextRenderer</renderer-type>
            <handler-class>com.unilife.emoticonOutputText.EmoticonOutputTextTag</handler-class>            
        </component>
        <attribute>
            <name>style</name>            
            <type>java.lang.String</type>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>styleClass</name>            
            <type>java.lang.String</type>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>inputText</name>
            <required>true</required>            
            <type>java.lang.String</type>
        </attribute>
    </tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

Now the problem is that `uic` cannot be cast to `EmoticonOutputText`..but why??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tag class extends from the wrong class. UIComponentELTag is for JSP. In Facelets, a tag handler can be provided for components extending from javax.faces.view.facelets.ComponentHandler and adding a < handler-class > inside < tag >< component > in your .taglib.xml file.

If you do not want to deal with all config stuff for create custom components, take a look at [MyFaces Builder Plugin Site](http://myfaces.apache.org/build-tools/plugins/myfaces-builder-plugin/index.html). It uses source-code annotations to handle all metadata and generate all related files with minimal effort. It is the tool used for [Apache MyFaces Core](http://myfaces.apache.org/core21/index.html), [Apache MyFaces Tomahawk](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/index.html) and MyFaces Sandbox. There is an archetype that helps to setup the environment using maven [See Instructions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MYFACES/MyFaces+Archetypes+for+Maven). Or you can take the "easy way" and create a JSF 2.0 composite component.

Comment: I've used UIComponentELTag because it's what Oracle says in their guide. Do you have any example on how to write a Facelet tag handler? I can't use a composite component because I've got to do something that goes beyond combining components ! I've downloaded myfaces-archetype-jsfcomponents20 but it doesn't have the TagHandler class! It's name is defined, but there isn't the file :\

Comment: I've added the new code with your edits, now I've got a new error :D